# Why I still get "http://localhost:8080" when I start my app by tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

I already set my  as below:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

When I click run in Netbeans everything is good but first page is still

```
http://localhost:8080
```

What else can I do ?
Do i need to configure another files in java code or tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome pages make sense in a context. If you have multiple WARs there would be multiple contexts each with a separate set of welcome-pages. Try deploying your app as a ROOT.war and test it to see if it is the case

See the following posts for more information.

- [Tomcat 6: How to change the ROOT application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application)
- [Set Tomcat Default Context Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640247/set-tomcat-default-context-path)

Answer (score 0):

Inside $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml there is a section called  and it looks like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The default servlet attempts to load the index.* files in the order listed. You may easily override the index.jsp file by creating an index.html file at $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT. It's somewhat common for that file to contain a new static home page or a redirect to a servlet's main page. A redirect would look like:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://webaddress.com/some/path/to/servlet/homepage/">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```